# Rails doesn't log into new log file after log rotation

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails

I am using `newsyslog` to rotate my log file in Rails application. The log rotates successfully, but Rails and Sidekiq still log to the old file (`development.log.0` and `sidekiq.log.0`).

After I restart my Rails and Sidekiq, they log normally into `development.log` and `sidekiq.log`.

How do I make them log properly after log rotation, without restart my server? Thanks.

Here is my `/etc/newsyslog.d/dev_logs.conf`:

`/Users/.../my_server/log/*.log me:staff 664  7      *       $D0     GN`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some `postrotate` script to your `logrotate` configuration that either restarts your app or send it a signal to close and reopen the log file so it doesn't continue to use its old filehandle that now points to the old file.

Comment: Hello Sven, I am using `newsyslog` instead of `logrotate` because that is the default for Mac OSX. Can you give example on how to `send it a signal to close and reopen the log file`? Thanks =]

Comment: Sorry, can't say. You can configure `newsyslog` to either send a Unix signal (e.g. HUP or USR2) to a process identified by the `path_to_pid_cmd_file` option or, with the `R` flag set, run a shell script also specified by `path_to_pid_cmd_file`. Then it's up to your Rails environment to gracefully handle this, but how that's done is a topic for [SO]. See [the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog.conf&sektion=5&n=1)